# chi square distrbution gives neagtive values

Tags: chi-squared

As I know the chi square probability density function depends on Bessel function and at some values the Bessel function give negative values and the pdf also.
How can I over come this problem or there is something I didn't under stand?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure about the Bessel functions. I am not saying you are wrong, I just have never seen the connection.

Comment: The chi-squared cdf is directly related to the incomplete Gamma integral, which is increasing.

Comment: I am talking about the probability density function of non central chi square distribution , it depends on the Bessel function of any kind according to the value of degree of freedom of the random variable . I tried the function on MATLAB and some values gives negative , which is wrong . thanks a lot